# I have a problem in an exercie about sets and sets of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set named $A$. This set is located in a set of sets named $T$. Knowing that $A$ is in $T$, I used this trick to prove the following:
Since $E$ is in $T$ then $A\cup \overline{A}$ is in $T$ (since $E=A\cup \overline{A}$) 
and so we have $A$ in $T$ and $A \cup \overline{A}$ is in $T$ 
from that we conclude that $\overline{A}$ is in $T$.
Is that correct?
If I made a mistake somewhere or violated some sort of law in the science of sets please clarify and thanks.

Comment: It is rather distracting to have to read "AUAbar" rather than $A\cup \overline{A}$.  Please check out [this page for a primer on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: As for your question, you have not given nearly enough description of the set $T$.  If you have certain known properties about $T$ then perhaps you might be able to conclude what you want, however with no known properties about $T$ you cannot make such a claim.  Suppose your universal set is $E=\{1,2\}$.  Suppose that $A=\{1\}$.  Finally suppose that $T=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$.  Notice that $\overline{A}=\{2\}$ is not an element of $T$ despite $A\cup \overline{A}=\{1,2\}$ is an element of $T$.

Comment: If you happened to know that $T$ was closed under set differences [such as is the case for sigma-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) and you know that your universal set $E$ were an element of $T$, then you would from that be able to conclude that $T$ were closed under set complementation as well., however again without knowing that $T$ were closed under set differences you would have no way of knowing whether or not $T$ were closed under complementation and it is possible (*as my example above shows*) that it is not.

Comment: thanks alot this really helped and yes T={X in P(E) with f-1(f(X))=X}